# Why does converting System.nanoTime() to a Calendar object give me the wrong current date?

Tags: java, android

If I understand correctly, using `System.nanoTime()` is a more accurate way of keeping a marker to the current time than `System.currentTimeInMillis()`, even if the system time was changed. So why is it that when I convert the long value of `nanoTime()` to a `Calendar` object, the output is wrong?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) +
                " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND)
                + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    }

}
```

Comment: `nanoTime` return time in nanoseconds, if you feed the value to `setTimeInMillis` there's an "unit-mismatch" (ns versus ms)

Comment: How can I resolve the unit mismatch?

Comment: What does your code have to do with the question? You do not use nanoTime. To convert ns to ms you just need to divide it by 10^6 ;)

Comment: AmitD answer is also to take into consideration!

Comment: I'm generally saving the current time when a `Service` in my Android app is executed. I read through similar questions that `nanoTime()` is a better marker for current time than `currentTimeInMillis()` because the latter can change when the system time was changed. I understood that correctly, right?

Comment: Careful with this. Dividing System.nanoTime() by 10^6 will NOT give you the milliseconds since 1970. You cannot create a Timestamp or Date with the result of System.nanoTime().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[System.nanotime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) javadoc suggests :

Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.
>
> For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Comment: Ah, so `nanoTime` is only useful to calculate a duration which is accurate to milliseconds.. it *doesn't represent nanoseconds since epoch* (Jan01/1970). I wonder why the official documentation uses so difficult english to explain it properly.